# Error Inflating class android.widget.checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, error-handling, exception

I have a Problem when i drag a checkbox widget onto the mobile screen and it says:

Error Inflating Class android.widget.checkbox

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 24

I have also tried:
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox in XML file.

What should i do now.

Comment: You should post the xml that is mentioned to cause the error, and post the **whole error** from the logcat here, please.

Comment: Thanks for your first and quick respone...
it was due to API 24 problems.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android API 24 have some issue will show issues error `no class definition com/android/util/properties/`  found can fix it by selection API 23.

**API 23 FIX**

[image]

**API 24 Error**

[image]

Comment: @SyedFurqan thats great if it helps please tick mark.